# How can i make notifications in django?

Tags: python, django

i have Movie model like This:

```py
class Movie(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    imdb = models.FloatField(validators=[MaxValueValidator(10), MinValueValidator(0)])
    age = models.IntegerField()
    description = models.TextField()
    starring = models.TextField()
    Genres = models.ForeignKey(
        Category, related_name="category", on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    tag = models.ManyToManyField(Category, related_name="tags")
    file = models.FileField(upload_to="media/movie")
    trailer = models.FileField(upload_to="media/movie/trailer")
    poster = models.ImageField(upload_to="media/poster", default="media/hero.png")
    no_likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.title

    @property
    def time(self):
        video = VideoFileClip(self.file.path)
        duration = video.duration
        hours = int(duration // 3600)
        min = int((duration % 3600) // 60)
        if min == 0:
            return f"{hours} h"
        elif hours == 0:
            return f"{min} min"
        else:
            return f"{hours} h {min} min"


    @property
    def star(self):
        return round(self.imdb / 2, 0)
```

and i have a Notifications Model like this:

```py
class Notifications(models.Model):
      user = models.Foreignkey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
      movie = models.Foreignkey(Movie,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I want to create an object from the notifications model when an object is created from the movie model
What should I do?

i try use signals but signals not work

Comment: How did you construct these signals?

Comment: Signal should solve this issue. Try `@receiver(post_save, sender=Movie)`
For example:
@receiver(post_save, sender=Movie)
def create_notification(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Notifications.objects.create(movie=instance, user=instance.user)  # Adjust as needed